# @gorhom/bottom-sheet not closing on index change

Tags: react-native, react-context, bottom-sheet

I have the bottom sheet set up with a login form in it:

```
import { useContext, useMemo, useRef } from "react";
import { GeneralContext } from "@/providers";
import BottomSheet from "@gorhom/bottom-sheet";
import LoginForm from "./LoginForm";

const AuthSheet = () => {
  const { showAuthModal } = useContext(GeneralContext);

  const bottomSheetRef = useRef(null);
  // variables
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ["30%"], []);

  const index = useMemo(() => {
    if (showAuthModal) {
      return 0;
    }
    return -1;
  }, [showAuthModal]);

  return (
    <BottomSheet
      ref={bottomSheetRef}
      index={index}
      enablePanDownToClose={true}
      snapPoints={snapPoints}
    >
      <LoginForm />
    </BottomSheet>
  );
};

export default AuthSheet;
```

Whenever the user logs in, the `showAuthModal` is set to `false` and the `index` will be set to -1 again. The Sheet however does not close at all. The other way around does work, if I use some button somewhere in my app to set the `showAuthModal` to `true`, the sheet will open. Could this be because I am calling the context from a child component that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [index](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/props#index) prop is only used to determine the initial position of the sheet, so its possible that `BottomSheet` only uses index for the initial render and ignores it entirely after that. Try using the `bottomSheetRef` for closing on auth changes:

```js
const AuthSheet = () => {
  const { showAuthModal } = useContext(GeneralContext);

  const bottomSheetRef = useRef(null);
  // variables
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ["30%"], []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!showAuthModal) {
     bottomSheetRef.current?.close?.()
    }
  }, [showAuthModal]);

  return (
    <BottomSheet
      ref={bottomSheetRef}
      index={showAuthModal ? 0 : -1}
      enablePanDownToClose={true}
      snapPoints={snapPoints}
    >
      <LoginForm />
    </BottomSheet>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yep that works, still feels a bit overkill though. Would kind of expect there to be some `show` prop

Comment: Also, wouldn't this hook then be better?   `useEffect(() => {
    showAuthModal
      ? bottomSheetRef.current?.expand?.()
      : bottomSheetRef.current?.close?.();
  }, [showAuthModal]);`

Comment: Yeah. I didnt read too deeply on the methods, so  I only looked for the close function I had seen in another bottomsheet component

Comment: Oh which component? Maybe there's an alternative

Comment: There's a [useBottomSheet](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/hooks) hook that you can use within `LoginForm` that will allow you to expand or close from that component